# Local SQL Changes To SQL Azure Database

Tags: c#, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a local database I am working on for a website, I can publish the website changes to azure but cannot see an easy way to just get my 'changes' pushed up to SQL Azure.

I used this https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ to initially get my local database onto Azure, but it seems to only support entire database migrations. Not minor changes like data, or a new field added?

This is my first time using Azure and it seems great, it's just this issue with the database which is now putting me off slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that without any third-party tool you will not be able to achieve much.

What I usually do is create migration sql scripts and run them directly against the production database after the scripts have been thoroughly tested

Comment: Create migration scripts? Do you do this manually or use a tool? I was hoping for something simple which would kind of 'diff' the databases and then apply changes

Comment: Actually, that's what a couple of companies I used to work with did. I remembered we trial a few of these tools specially one from RedGate which we used for a while but there were one issue or another. Software development doesn't come simple sometimes

Answer (score 0):

If you manage your database schema using Visual Studio Database project then you can sync it with the SQL Azure database. I believe you can also sync data but I have not used that.